# Tray Icon Visibility Setting Resets After WPF App Update

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, trayicon, appinstaller

I'm working on a .NET 6.0 WPF application with a tray icon (WinForms). After updating the app via ms-appinstaller, the tray icon's visibility setting in the Taskbar resets, moving it back to the hidden area. The package info (name, publisher, certificate, ProjectGuid) remains the same.

**How can I prevent this behavior and maintain the icon's visibility setting across updates?**

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you talking about a WPF app installed though Microsoft Store (Desktop bridge)?

Comment: Yes, it's a WPF application but published per app-installer, not the store